# R: durbin watson test not found

Tags: r

I'm trying to obtain the Durban Watson statistic for a regression I'm running in R. However, when I run the code `dw.test(x~y)`, R keeps telling me `Error: could not find function "dw.test"`. I've checked and the dw.test function is part of the bstats package, which is a base package.

Does anyone have any idea why R is unable to recognise the dw.test function?

Thank you!

Mike

Comment: The package `stats` is a base package, but `bstats` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package ‘bstats’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2).

Try:

```
library(lmtest)
err1 <- rnorm(100)
x <- rep(c(-1,1), 50)
y1 <- 1 + x + err1
dwtest(y1 ~ x)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to import the function from outside of base R. Try

```
library(car)
dwt(lm(x ~ y))
```

or

```
durbinWatsonTest(lm(x ~ y))
```